# Does "including all environments" with the RCP SDK fully replace adding a Delta Pack to the target platform?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, cross-platform, eclipse-rcp, delta-pack

I'm building an Eclipse RCP application, and am in the process of setting up the **target platform**.

In ["Eclipse Rich Client Platform" 2nd edition](http://eclipsercp.org/) it is noted that one should uncheck the "*include required software*" option when adding the `RCP SDK` to the target definition, and install the `Delta Pack`. This is mentioned across the web as well.

A second option, however, is to **uncheck** the "include required software" option, so that one can select "**include all environments**". This isn't mentioned in the book, but it is mentioned acros the web.

So my question basically is: When unchecking the "include required software", should I then (in terms of a "best practice" or similar)

1. leave the "include all environments" *unchecked*, and *install a Delta Pack*, or
2. *check* the "include all environments" option?

And furthermore, if 2. is preferrable, do I still have to install the *Delta Pack*, or is checking the option "include all environments" a **full replacement** for installing a Delta Pack?

Further info that might (?) influence answers: I plan to build with *Tycho*...

Many thanks in advance to all who help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not actually used this (because it's very new), but I think your suspicions are correct according to the documentation. Option 2 is the best choice and you therefore don't need the delta pack.

The delta pack has been around for ages and that's how you get the plugins that are specific for all environments. It looks like with this new thing based on getting stuff from p2 that it can easily get the plugins for all environments that way, eliminating the need to manually install the delta pack.

You can certainly verify this when you build to make sure you have the os-specific plugins for your desired environments (look at the SWT plugins for example).